# Why $S\cong A/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules

Let $A$ a $\mathbb K-$algebra of finite dimension where $\mathbb K$ is an algebraically closed field and let $S$ a simple $A-$module. In the proof of the Schur lemma, it says that since $S\cong A/I$ for a certain ideal $I$ of $A$, $S$ is a $\mathbb K$-vector space of finite dimension.

My question:

1) What would be an ideal of an algebra ?

2) Why $S\cong A/I$ for a certain ideal $I$ of $A$ ?

3) Why this implies that $S$ is a $\mathbb K-$vector space ? And why of finite dimension ?

Sorry, it's maybe obvious, but I can't justify anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (left) ideal $I$ of $A$ is a vector subspace such that $ai\in I$ for every $a$ in $A$ and $i$ in $I$

Let $s\in S$, the set of elements $f(a)=as$ $a\in A$ is a sub module, since $S$ is simple, it is $S$. The kernel of $f$ is an ideal $I$. Thus $S$ is the quotient of $A$ by an ideal.

Since $A$ is finite dimensional, $S$ is finite dimensional as the quotient of the finite dimensional space $A$.

Comment: that is a left ideal, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, left ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So do you think that if $A(+,\cdot ,*)$ is the algebra, it would have sens to says that $I$ is in fact the ideal of $A(+,*)$ (if it's a ring, but I think it is, no ?)

Comment: Yes it is an ideal of $A$.

Comment: Just to confirm, if $A$ is an algebra, does $A(+,*)$ a ring ?